# android:hint declared in styles.xml but still have warning "You should provide an `android:hint`" for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

The title sums it up well: I use in my activity several EditTexts, each one for the name of a different player. So they have everything in common, that's why I created a style to apply it to all of them.
The problem is that even if I initialized android:hint in my style, the warning is still: "Missing accessibility label: where minSdk < 17, you should provide an `android:hint`". Is there any way to fix this warning (other than using tools:ignore)?
Of course defining android:hint in edit_text.xml would be a solution, but if so : (why) is it not recommended to do it in styles.xml? Is this done on purpose or a bug?

edit_text.xml:

```
<!-- Warning on `EditText` -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_player2"
    style="@style/EditTextPlayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="username" />
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="EditTextPlayer">
    <item name="android:minEms">8</item>
    <item name="android:maxLength">12</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
    <item name="textSize">@dimen/button</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/black_background</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textFilter|textNoSuggestions</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">flagNoFullscreen|actionDone</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:hint">@string/player_name</item> <!-- hint is here ^^ -->
</style>
```

P.S.
You can notice that I left in edit_text.xml the attribute `android:autofillHints`, because it gives an error in styles.xml (requires API level 26).

Comment: Of course defining `android:hint` in edit_text.xml would be a solution, but if so : (why) is it not recommended to do it in styles.xml? Is this done on purpose or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a string resource inside the strings.xml with the name "player_name".

```
 <string name="player_name">Insert your name here</string>
```

Comment: It is already defined... The only warning I got is "You should provide an `android:hint`" on the tag `EditText`, but I define it in the styles.xml.